# Adding Custom Security Provider for Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to statically add a new security provider to Android.
In particular, I want to add additional signature implementations to be used by other applications, not only mine.

Under standard Java there is a file $JAVA_HOME$/lib/security/java.security where I can add a new provider which is then used by all other applications which use the JCA.
"Forking" applications to only add one line of code is seems to be a bit of overkill.

However, I cannot find this file under Android. Currently, I am using a Nexus 10 tablet with Android 4.4 for development. Apparently, there the aforementioned file does exist in the Android source, but I was not able to find it on my device. I am not willing/allowed to root/flash the device. I assume that I cannot do this programmatically, but is there another way of adding that provider for all programs?
Or where can I find that file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else faces the same problem:

It seems that what I want is not achievable with the current code base.
I.e., I had to fork the complete SSL/TLS stack.

I have opened a bug report:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80353

Hope this helps anyone looking for answers regarding this.